# Thank you, Torben and cabbey!

Tags: discussion, moderation

It's with a bit of a heavy heart that I must inform you that two *exemplary* Parenting SE moderators will be stepping down shortly:

[image: profile for Torben Gundtofte-Bruun at Parenting Stack Exchange, Q&A for parents, grandparents, nannies and others with a parenting role]


[image: profile for cabbey at Parenting Stack Exchange, Q&A for parents, grandparents, nannies and others with a parenting role]

I've worked with them not only as an employee of Stack Exchange, but also as a long-term Stack Exchange moderator myself. Torben and cabbey stepped up to help lead a new kind of community on Stack Exchange, coming together to build a site around a topic that many considered to be experimental. They have done an *astounding* job and deserve our thanks and well wishes as they turn their attention to new and exciting adventures.

They're not gone for good, both will be staying around as a part of this community, but they won't be handling things in an official capacity for much longer.

***Torben and cabbey, thank you for everything that you've done for this site and community.*** You've done great things, and will always hold a special place here.

They'll be staying on for a little while longer [while we identify some replacements](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/moderators-wanted-apply-inside), which we hope to do in the coming week. Please feel free to use answers to this post for any good wishes you might want to give them as they transition back into extraordinary, but ordinary users.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you, Torben and Cabbey!  It's been a pleasure working with you on this site.  You've both been invaluable here, and your contributions very much appreciated.

We absolutely could not have made it this far without you.

I wish you both the best of luck, and I hope that you realize how grateful we are for your efforts over these past few years.

Please don't be strangers!  Chat wouldn't be the same without you! :)

Answer (score 4):

I sincerely appreciate the positive reactions I've received. I tell myself it's not because I might *finally* stop nagging people but rather because I've actually done something to help keep things nice around here! :-)

Don't worry, I won't disappear. I'll still be around, I'll still participate. I know that my reputation points grant me access to the mod tools even without being a moderator, so resigning is mostly a symbolic action, but it's an action that has meaning to me. I look forward to participating *just as a user* because I've realized that I felt some kind of obligation that kept me from focusing on other aspects in my life.

Thank you for providing this wonderful platform, and thank you for the many pleasant and intelligent interactions we've had. I have really enjoyed it so far, and I've learned *a lot.* You're welcome to [keep in touch](http://torben.g-b.dk/+) for any reason (or for no reason at all). I will remain available if you need me for any particular task, and I want to ensure a smooth transition to new moderators.