# Please welcome your new moderators, Balanced Mama and Karl Bielefeldt

Tags: discussion, moderators

After [Torben And Cabbey stepped down](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/580/thank-you-torben-and-cabbey), we began [the search for some new awesome moderators](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/moderators-wanted-apply-inside) to lead the Parenting SE community toward its goal of graduation.

I'm happy to say, we've found two excellent choices:

[image: profile for balanced mama at Parenting Stack Exchange, Q&A for parents, grandparents, nannies and others with a parenting role]


[image: profile for Karl Bielefeldt at Parenting Stack Exchange, Q&A for parents, grandparents, nannies and others with a parenting role]

Both long-term users of the site have shown nothing but patience, fairness and a desire to help newcomers to the Parenting SE community. They've been doing the job of a moderator for a while, we think it's about time we gave them diamonds so that they can do it more effectively. Already excited to work together, they step up to their posts today.

A special thanks from us to everyone that stepped up and offered to help. We hope to be looking forward to democratic moderator elections in the not too distant future, you'd all do well to nominate yourselves at that time, I'm sure all of you would do an excellent job.

Please give Balanced Mama and Karl a warm welcome as they step into their new roles!

Comment: Excellent additions to an already awesome community!

Answer (score 4):

**Welcome!**

You've both been wonderful for this site, and I look forward to your continued contributions as moderators!

Comment: From me as well - great things are ahead, and it's good to have sensible people at the helm :-)